# why does it give this error when I run create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

whenever i run create-react-app command it shows this thing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dg7y.png)

It was running fine earlier but it isn't working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to uninstall any installs of React that you may have mistakenly installed globally? Try the commands that appear inside the warning message:
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
or for yarn: `yarn global remove create-react-app`.

After that you may use create-react-app, this time locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you've `create-react-app` installed globally using the following command:

- `npm list -g --depth=0`
- `yarn list global`

If you see `create-react-app` in the list returned from the above command (*which you probably would*), just uninstall it using the command below and then the command should work properly.

- `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
- `yarn global remove create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

As 'create-react-app' is updated to version 5.0.1
So you need to update your 'create-react-app' also to work properly.

Firstly Uninstall 'create-react-app'
Globally using below command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then again Globally install it using below command . It will update your 'create-react-app' to latest version

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Then you should able to create your react app properly.

Good luck .